# Print out colors used in a color ramp?

Tags: r

I want to manually manipulate the colors I plot by from a color ramp.  So right now I am using a code like this:

```
library(colorRamps)

plot(object, col = blue2red(10))
```

I want to be able to manually change one color in this color ramp sequence though.  Is there a way to return the 10 colors being used in this ramp, and then edit just one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cols <- blue2red(10) # store colors in object
cols[2] <- "black" # change second element to black
barplot(rep(1, length(cols)), names.arg = cols, col = cols)
```

Comment: I'm curious, I ran my code without `names.arg = cols` and it worked fine, what does that argument do?

Comment: adds the labels